# How to chain css:watch and babel in package.json

Tags: reactjs, sass, babeljs

In the package.json of my react App I would like to watch my css when I execute build:watch. If I add the watch-css to build:watch, but then the babel is not executed anymore.

```
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o ./src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "build": "watch-css babel --source-maps inline -d dist/ src/,
    "build:watch": "npm run build -- --watch"
```

Answer (score 0):

"build-watch": "npm run build -- --watch"
use this it may I also get that one previously  it working now